# Ajax returns 404 even with request success

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, http-status-code-404

The problem is that I'm uodating some few line in a database table with ajax request, When I try to make sure that the update has been successful, it returns with a 404 header, I go to network tools and I see 404 as shown in the screenshot bellow :

[image: 404 header screenshot]

this the code that I have for both js and php

PHP :

```
<?php 
include("../../db_connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['ads_left'])) {

    $ads_left = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect , $_POST['ads_left']);
    $ads_right = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect , $_POST['ads_right']);
    $ads_top = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect , $_POST['ads_top']);
    $ads_bottom = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect , $_POST['ads_bottom']);

    $ads_left = htmlentities($ads_left);
    $ads_right = htmlentities($ads_right);
    $ads_top = htmlentities($ads_top);
    $ads_bottom = htmlentities($ads_bottom); 

    $ads_array = array();
    $ads_array[0] = $ads_top;
    $ads_array[1] = $ads_right;
    $ads_array[2] = $ads_bottom;
    $ads_array[3] = $ads_left;

    for ((int) $i = 0 ; $i<4 ; $i++) {
        $j = $i+1;
        $ins_ads_query = "UPDATE ads SET code = '$ads_array[$i]' WHERE id = '{$j}'";
        $result_ads = mysqli_query($connect , $ins_ads_query);
    }

} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}

?>
```

JS :

```
var adsTop = document.getElementById('top');
var adsRight = document.getElementById('right');
var adsBottom = document.getElementById('bottom');
var adsLeft = document.getElementById('left');

var adsSubmit = document.getElementById("ads_submit");

function updateAds(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    adsSubmit.innerHTML = "Saving <i class=\"fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin\" style=\"font-size:24px\"></i>";

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'ajax/update_ads.php';

    var params = 'ads_top='+adsTop.value+'&ads_right='+adsRight.value+'&ads_bottom='+adsBottom.value+'&ads_left='+adsLeft.value;
    http.open('POST', url, true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    http.send(params);

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            adsSubmit.innerHTML = "Saved <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved\"></span>";
        }
    }
}


adsSubmit.addEventListener('click' , function(e) {
    updateAds(e);
});
```

it's very strange, I really couldn't know what provokes that 404 header, I you guys could be of any help, I would be really thankful.

Comment: Agree with @charlietfl, the else statement makes no sense in an AJAX response.

Comment: @charlietfl no that's not the problem I've just tried that, I did that to redirect user if they hotlinked this file

Comment: 404 would mean that `ajax/update_ads.php` is not found - what is the whole URL of the POST request in the developer tools network tab?

Comment: OK so is the actual url that request gets sent to in same path you expect? Might need to change to `var url = '/ajax/update_ads.php';` if ajax directory is at root level

Comment: @charlietfl yes, the update query goes well, I look into the database and I seed the value have changed but the response is 404 ! 
it just doesn't make any sens

Comment: Are you using a php framework that has a router in it? You don't appear to be but just asking

Comment: @charlietfl ,  No I'm using php as it is.

Comment: That's what I thought. Just trying to narrow possibilities down. Have no idea why short of something wierd in htaccess file

Comment: @charlietfl no I don't have it in my development environment

Comment: And you don't set any status header anywhere in your code?

Comment: @charlietfl this is what I have 
`if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
 header("Location: ../index.php");
}`
it's only for a redirect

Comment: If you use prepared statements you can cut out the escaping.

Comment: Hard to figure this one out without having access to it

Comment: @charlietfl at the moment I'm just ignoring that 404, and having the condition on the readystate == 4 only